# How to make another List in Java, given a List, but with a different class listed

Tags: java, list, generics, instance

I have a list, and I need to return that same type of list.

If it's relevant, in my case Y is an interface and interface X is its superinterface.

I assume that I need to use newInstance to get the type of List.

```
public List<Y> foo() {
    List<X> xList = -a method that returns List<X>-;
    List<Y> yList = xList.getClass().newInstance(); //Is this right?

    ...

    return yList;
}
```

I could just make an ArrayList, but I don't know if that's the best thing to do since I could receive any type of list.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you just share what you need it for? The first look says that you are probably trying to do something very simple in the most complex way.

Comment: why cant you use it as a `List` object itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you mixing up the class of the List with its generic type? There should rarely be any need to return a particular implementation of `List` (e.g., if it needs to be serializable). I recommend just using an `ArrayList`, sized appropriately beforehand.

With regards to the interfaces, be careful because if `Y` extends `X`, you can't in general put objects from `xList` in `yList` (I assume you want to), because there might be an instance of `X` in the list that isn't a `Y`.

Comment: Thanks for the warning, but I convert them anyway so I know they're all Y's.

Answer (score 0):

Java implements generics via erasure, so at runtime you will see no difference between the `.getClass()` of a `List<X>` and that of a `List<Y>`. However, you should be able to just say:

```
List<Y> yList = new ArrayList<Y>(); // Or LinkedList, or whatever implementation you want.
```

If you don't know which List implementation to use, and that's what you want to have depend on the list type backing `xList`, you can still use `newInstance`: you just have to cast it:

```
List<Y> yList = (List<Y>)xList.getClass().newInstance();
```

At runtime, all you'll have is a `LinkedList` or `ArrayList` or some such, but as long as you don't add any non-Y items to the list, you should be safe returning it as a `List<Y>`.

Comment: I think his point was to create a new list of the same type as an existing list, which is not known at compile time.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen: Thanks for the input. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was asking.

Comment: @user1195265: I'd be curious to know why, exactly, you need this behavior. Are you sure it matters that you preserve the original list implementation? Do you really even need a new list?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I might be wrong about actually needing this solution, but I wanted to be sure. Also it was driving me crazy not knowing the answer! @_@

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Technically it's only supposed to support ArrayList, but if just changing this one part can allow for use of custom X classes with custom List classes while working the same with the default, then why not? P.S. It has to do with Bukkit.

Comment: @user1195265: Depending on what you're actually planning to do with the list, it usually shouldn't matter whether you have custom X classes or custom List classes as input: they satisfy the interface you're inputting and the interface you're returning. I think I'm going to delete my answer soon, since JB's is probably the answer you're looking for. You should mark his answer correct unless you need additional clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know the type of the List, you don't know if it has a public no-arg constructor either, so you can't be sure that newInstance() won't throw an exception.

If you don't want a copy of the list, and you know that the list actually contains Y instances, you could just do

```
List<Y> yList = (List) xList;
```

Comment: In my particular case, I think this solution is the best fit.

Comment: @JBNizet: I apologize, I misread the answer. I thought it said "If you *just* want a copy of the list", and now StackOverflow won't let me remove my downvote unless you edit the answer.

Comment: OK. No need to remove your downvote. I just wondered why I had a downvote. Now things are clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Y> yList = (List<Y>) xList.getClass().newInstance();
```

will work only if the no-args constructor is available. If it is not accessible, you may need to override the access visibility using reflection:

```
final Constructor cons = xList.getClass().getDeclaredConstructor();
cons.setAccessible(true);
List<Y> yList = (List<Y>) cons.newInstance();
```

If there is no no-args constructor available for the Class, then you are probably out of luck!
It is advised for implementing classes to provide a constructor of the form:

```
public MyListClass(Collection<T> items)
```

If such a constructor exists, you may try invoking that constructor using reflection and passing it an empty List. It will not be possible, in the general case, to determine which constructor to call :(